# how to install bitly on heroku running rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I added this to environment.rb

```
config.gem 'bitly'
```

And I added this to .gems

```
bitly
```

But when I do "git push heroku" I get this error:

```
-----> Installing gem bitly from http://gemcutter.org, http://rubygems.org
       ERROR:  Error installing bitly:
        multi_json requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gem
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`.gems` is deprecated on Heroku. As per the docs, [you should be using Bundler instead](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gems).

Comment: thanks - i'll look into bundler.  our system is in production and has been running great for more than a year and i was hoping not to have to change things around.  it doesn't look simple either - http://gembundler.com/rails23.html  oh well.